# Why one interval id can manage two intervals at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I am reading *Secrets of the JS Ninja(Second Edition)*. In Chapter 5.2.2, there is a demo that shows the problem about polluting the global scope while using interval callbacks.

https://jsfiddle.net/tinachen/8fd8t355/

By watching these variables in debugger, I understand that `timer` is set to `2`(interval id of box2).

My question is that why these two intervals still runing 
alternately, and when `clearInterval(timer);` executed, the interval of box2 is cleared, why the interval of box1 is still running ? Why one interval id can manage two intervals at the same time?

Comment: `timer` is *not* set to 2 for both intervals, see https://jsfiddle.net/8fd8t355/5/. It only looks that way because in the original code you log its value when it has already been overwritten by the second function call.

Comment: @JJJ, https://jsfiddle.net/tinachen/8fd8t355/6/ If it is not two interval functions, why the argument `elementId` shows alternately?

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to have completely misunderstood the comment. I didn't say that there aren't two intervals. I said that there are two timer references, so *"Why one interval id can manage two intervals at the same time?"* is a false premise because there are *two* interval ids, not one.

Comment: Thanks ! I got it . Interval function of box1 is looping forever to clear box2's interval id. So... should I delete this question or change the title?

Comment: The question is fine, that was the original question which got answered so no need to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not managing 2 intervals. In the following code:

```
console.log("box1 call")
animateIt('box1');
// timer is now 1
console.log("box2 call")
animateIt('box2');
// timer is now immediately overwritten and becomes 2
```

The first call to `animateIt` calls `setInterval`, which sets up the first `timer` value. Immediately after, that value is overwritten by the second call. Due to the nature of the global scope, only the second call to `setInterval` has the value stored in the `timer` variable. As such, the first call to `setInterval` will loop forever, because the value was clobbered by calling storing that different value in `timer`.